# Second component not rendering below first one - REACT JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am making a personal website. The landing page is the first component. The second page is the About component but it is not rendering below the landing component. It is appearing at the top.

**App.js file:**

```
import "./App.css";
import Landing from "./components/Landing/Landing";
import About from "./components/About/About";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Landing/>
      <About/>
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

**App.css file: **

```
.App{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width: 8px;
  }
  
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
  background: black;
  border-radius: 1ex;
  }
  
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
  background: #427898;
  border-radius: 1ex;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background: black;
  }
  
  a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit
  }
```

**About.jsx file:**

```
import React from 'react'
import css from "./About.module.css"

const About = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ color: 'white' }}>About</div>
  )
}

export default About
```

I have already tried creating a container class for About and then changing the display in my About.module.css file but the About text still remains at the top of the page unseen.[This is the landing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAVoo.png) and as you can see I want the About component to now be below the landing page as you scroll down.

Comment: Should work fine